# Are there any significant integer constants that are not unitless?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, si-units, discrete

When it comes to meaningful integer constants, the only ones I can come to think of (except zero) are unitless, for example 1 (the multiplicative identity), 2 (the base of the binary system), 10 (the number of fingers on most human beings and the base of the decimal system), or the prime numbers.

Is it so that any meaningful (non-zero) constant that is an integer will also be unitless, at least when using the SI system, and if so, does this principle have any name? Or are there examples of physical constants that are integers but not unitless, that are still meaningful and useful?

**Edit:** I realize that $c$ is an integer constant that is not unitless when using SI units. But this is a bit unsatisfying, considering that the number itself, 299792458, doesn’t really bare any mathematical significance, and it happens to be an integer simply because the SI unit m was defined specifically so that $c$ would become an integer.

Comment: What is "meaningful" anyway? (Btw. 10, the base of the most commonly used system of numbers should spring to mind in your first paragraph.)

Comment: Perhaps the length of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_metre#International_prototype_metre? (Ok, not really a physical constant like $c$ or $h$.)

Comment: I was just about to mention Avogadro's constant before you made your edit. Your edit renders the question difficult to handle, I think, if usable at all. What is "mathematical significance" supposed to be?

Comment: @kricheli That’s a good question, and I’m not really sure exactly what I’m after myself (hence asking if there is any such principle). The thought emerged as I was reading a post about the numbers 3, 6, and 9, which Nikola Tesla apparently was obsessed with, and how the frequencies 3 Hz, 6 Hz and 9 Hz supposedly emerged naturally in the universe. My instinctual reaction to the claim about the frequencies is that it cannot be correct, since it is based on the unit Hz, which is artificial. It would be easier to express these thoughts if there were some principle that I could just refer to.

Comment: Ok. Every system of units will be artificial. And through definitions we are probably likely to end up with dimensional constants that are integer in a constructed system of units. However, for a really random choice of system of units I would argue that there is zero probability of having integer constants because the integers are a set of measure zero in the reals. :)

Comment: Does the atomic mass of $^{12}C$ count? Or does it fail under the same rule that the unit was defined in such a way as to make it an integer?

Comment: "integer" is a math concept.  Physics concepts are best expressed with math, but physics is NOT math.

Comment: @ThePhoton What do you mean by "$^{\,12}C$ count"?

Comment: Do you consider the atomic mass of $^{12}C$ a valid answer to your question?

Comment: @ThePhoton I misread your question; now I see what you mean. Well, I guess so. Although I'm not really sure myself what I am asking for at this point.

Answer (score 1):

[Electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) always comes in integer multiples of
$1.602\times 10^{-19}$ coulomb (the so-called elementary charge $e$),
as was first measured in [Millikan's oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) (1909).

Comment: Except quarks, which have 1/3 or 2/3 charges (also in multiples of $e$).

Comment: @Miyase Well, but those non-integer quark charges haven't been measured directly.
And theory predicts, they will never be.

Comment: Okay, so what is the integer, non-unitless constant here?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye E.g. the charge of the electron is $-e$, the charge of
an iron nucleus is $+26\ e$, etc.

Comment: But what  is the constant here? Do you mean that all natural numbers are physical constants because the may express the number of electrons? Why not the mass expressed in multiple of atomic mass? These are not constants, just values of physical quantities.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any significant integer constants that are not unitless?

Values that are not unitless are called “dimensionful”.

Unfortunately, this question is not meaningful. The numerical value of any dimensionful constant is completely arbitrary. It depends entirely on the completely arbitrary choice of units. Therefore you can always choose a set of units designed to make any given dimensionful constant equal to any value you like, including any integer. If you want the max designed torque of a 2020 Dodge Ram to have an integer value, you can manufacture a set of units to do that. Same with the speed of light or Planck’s constant or any other dimensionful quantity.